# How is SUN rotating?

Tags: sun, solar-system, solar-system-exploration

Is Sun rotating anti clockwise similar to planet Venus or is it continuously changing it rotation ?

Comment: Completely and comprehensively answered by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_rotation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sun rotates in anti-clockwise direction (when viewed from the north).

The Sun, however, does not rotate as a whole body. It is made up of gaseous plasma and the time taken to complete one rotation increases with latitude. It takes around 25 days at equator and 38 days at poles (it is judged by the location of sun spots).

Comment: One should also mention that the rotation of the inner radiative zone is almost uniform, while that of the convective zone is also radius dependent.

Comment: Is there any possibility that this convention may create optical illusion on photosphere. which is why,it is making the outer zone look  like a non uniform rotation.